# Typescript Property 'X' is missing in type 'AxiosResponse' but required in type 'Pick<Y, "X">'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hi I have complex structure and I need to set type for my customer object, which I get from AxiosResponse

Here is Order Structure:

```
export interface Order {
  id: string;
  tenantId: string;
  orderStatus: string;
  orderType: string;
  customer: Customer;
  account: Account;
  consents: Consents;
  orderItems: OrderItem[];
  deliveryAddress: Address;
}
```

I am trying to pick customer from Order but I get error:

```
const existingOrderData = await getOrderData.execute(orderId);
const { customer }: Pick<Order, 'customer'> = existingOrderData;
```

**Property 'customer' is missing in type 'AxiosResponse' but required in type 'Pick<Order, "customer">'.**

How to take out Order from AxiosResponse and assign type correctly?

existingOrderData type is :

```
const getOrderData: UseAsyncReturn<AxiosResponse<Order>, [args?: string | undefined]>
```

Comment: AxiosResponse is the type of response you get from axios. Its property `data` is the data you actually get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
const { customer }: Pick<Order, 'customer'> = existingOrderData.data;
```

Had to tarket AxiosResponse data prop.